# git push still asking for credentials even after caching credentials

Tags: git, authentication, github, git-bash

So I cached my credentials because I was sick of entering my GitHub credentials every push, but it still asks me to enter credentials, although it's a bit different. I get a pop-up - as always - to enter my credentials, I enter them and it says "Logout failed" - as always - but this time the tkinter pop-up doesn't show up, and it pushes successfully. Here's the message:

```
$ git push
(Credential pop-up pops up, I enter my credentials)
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 311 bytes | 311.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To https://github.com/Crabby11/crab-line-interface
   467e5b9..ef76485  main -> main
```

I also added an SSH key to my GitHub account but that doesn't seem to matter.

NOTE: If you don't know what I want, it's: Not get the pop-up when I do `git push`

EDIT: Even when I input the wrong credentials, or click "Cancel", it pushes successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also added an SSH key to my GitHub account but that doesn't seem to matter.

Correct: an HTTPS URL would not involve SSH in any way, so no amount of SSH key registration would help.

Check first which credential helper you are using ("git-bash" suggests you are on Windows), and make sure to use the latest Git (for instance, [Git For Windows 2.30](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.30.0.windows.2))

Make sure git config credential.helper is then set (at least on Windows) to `manager-core`.

Finally, if you have [GitHub 2FA](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa) activated, try and enter as a password a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token).

Comment: >Make sure git config credential.helper is then set (at least on Windows) to manager-core.

What do you mean by that? And how do I do that?

Comment: @CrabbyFish By typing `git config credential.helper manager-core`. Are you on Windows? Are you using git 2.30?

Comment: also, when I do the command ```git config credential.helper```, it outputs "wincred"

Comment: @CrabbyFish wincred is now obsolete and deprecated. Make sure to use the lastest Git 2.30, and use manager-core.

Comment: i am using git version 2.28.0.windows.1

Comment: ill upgrade to 2.30

Comment: @CrabbyFish Perfect, upgrading is a good idea, then check your credential.helper config.

Comment: its still wincred

Comment: when I try ```git config credential.helper manager-core```, it gives me ```fatal: not in a git directory```.

Comment: wait, when I do ```git push```, it doesn't ask me for credentials anymore! Upgrading worked!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227884/discussion-between-vonc-and-crabby-fish).